# The dimension of an orthogonal complement and the norms of components

Tags: linear-algebra

The following I ask in relation to the Peter Rosenthal's article about Levy-Steinitz theorem, https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_17/levy.pdf. The assumption on $v$ is that $\|v\| \leq 1$. By $(v|L)$ we mean the inner product of $v$ and $L$.

1. How can one prove that $L^{\perp} := \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n: (v|L) = 0\}$ is $n - 1$ - dimensional space ("We use the inductive hypothesis in the $(n-1)$ - dimensional space)?
2. How can one prove that $\bigg \|v - \frac{(v|L)}{\|L\|^2}L \bigg\| \leq 1$ ("the component of a vector $v$ in $L^{\perp}$")?
3. How can one prove that ("the components along $L$") $\bigg \|\frac{(v|L)}{\|L\|^2}L \bigg\| \leq 1$?

Answer (score 1):

These are general facts about inner product spaces. Note that the inner product is a nondegenerate positive definite bilinear form.

1. The orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ of any nonzero vector $v$ is always a $1$-codimensional subspace, because of the orthogonal projection used in 2. and 3. prove $v^\perp+{\rm span}(v) =V $, and of course $v^\perp \cap{\rm span}(v)=\{0\}$. Then use the dimension theorem.
2. It's basically the Pythagorean theorem: the point is that $v$ is expressed as $v=a+b$ with $a\perp b$, and then we have $(a|b)=0$, hence 
   $$\|v\|^2 =\|a+b\|^2=(a+b\, |\, a+b) =(a\,|\, a) +(b\, |\, b) =\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2 \ge\max(\|a\|^2,\, \|b\|^2)$$
   So we have $\|a\|, \|b\|\, \le\|v\|\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I see that your second point refers to the second and third point in my question. About the first point, your claims are geometrically intuitive, but how do you use the dimension theorem and what exactly do you mean by it (Given a vector space V, any two bases have the same cardinality?)?

Comment: The dimension theorem says that for any two subspaces $A$ and $B$, we have $\dim(A+B) +\dim(A\cap B) =\dim A+\dim B$.